# python3.9 installation missing files latest kali@win10

Tags: kali-linux, python3, windows-subsystem-for-linux

```
└─# cat /etc/issue
Kali GNU/Linux Rolling \n \l

┌──(rootDESKTOP-NF4O0MG)-[~]
└─# uname -a
Linux DESKTOP-NF4O0MG 4.4.0-19041-Microsoft #488-Microsoft Mon Sep 01 13:43:00 PST 2020 x86_64 GNU/Linux
┌──(rootDESKTOP-NF4O0MG)-[~]
└─#
```

I am getting below error while trying to install p3.9 on kali linux installed on windows10. Has any one encountered these errors. The errors says about missing files. But don't know how it is missed or is it missed because of an uninstalled package of either python or OS

```
─#  apt install python3
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
python3 is already the newest version (3.9.0-4).
python3 set to manually installed.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
libllvm10 libperl5.30 libpython3.8 libpython3.8-dev libre2-8 libxcb-util0 perl-modules-5.30 python3.8-dev
Use 'apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
603 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up systemd-sysv (246.6-4) ...
Setting up libpython3-dev:amd64 (3.9.0-4) ...
Setting up python3 (3.9.0-4) ...
running python rtupdate hooks for python3.9...
/usr/share/legion/ui/models/cvemodels.py:55: SyntaxWarning: "is not" with a literal. Did you mean "!="?
if not len(self.__cves) is 0:
/usr/share/legion/ui/models/hostmodels.py:43: SyntaxWarning: "is not" with a literal. Did you mean "!="?
if not len(self.__hosts) is 0:
/usr/share/legion/ui/models/processmodels.py:43: SyntaxWarning: "is not" with a literal. Did you mean "!="?
if not len(self.__processes) is 0:
/usr/share/legion/ui/models/scriptmodels.py:44: SyntaxWarning: "is not" with a literal. Did you mean "!="?
if not len(self.__scripts) is 0:
/usr/share/legion/ui/models/servicemodels.py:40: SyntaxWarning: "is not" with a literal. Did you mean "!="?
if not len(self.__services) is 0:
/usr/share/legion/ui/models/servicemodels.py:184: SyntaxWarning: "is not" with a literal. Did you mean "!="?
if not len(self.__serviceNames) is 0:
/usr/share/responder/settings.py:209: SyntaxWarning: "is not" with a literal. Did you mean "!="?
if len(self.NumChal) is not 16 and not "random":
/usr/share/responder/tools/MultiRelay.py:418: SyntaxWarning: "is not" with a literal. Did you mean "!="?
if data.find("NTLM") is not -1:
/usr/share/responder/tools/MultiRelay.py:423: SyntaxWarning: "is not" with a literal. Did you mean "!="?
if data.find("NTLM") is not -1:
/usr/share/responder/tools/RunFingerPackets.py:14: SyntaxWarning: "is" with a literal. Did you mean "=="?
if PY2OR3 is "PY2":
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/set/src/payloads/set_payloads/multi_pyinjector.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/set/src/payloads/set_payloads/pyinjector_args.py'
Sorry: ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes
error running python rtupdate hook set
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/unicorn-magic/unicorn.py'
error running python rtupdate hook unicorn-magic
dpkg: error processing package python3 (--configure):
installed python3 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 4
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-adblockparser:
python3-adblockparser depends on python3:any; however:
Package python3 is not configured yet.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
apt purge python3.9
apt install -f -y
apt install python
```

solved this problem